# React - Set State and get value simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a ToDo App with React.  I have the following data:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        name:"Michael",
        tasks:[
            {task:"Go to the gym", completed:false, id:1 }, 
            {task:"Do yoga", completed:false, id:2 },
            {task:"Buy groceries", completed:true, id:3 },
            {task:"Get tire fixed", completed:true, id:4}
        ],
        numCompleted:null
    }
},
```

How can I get the value of numCompleted to be shown in the initial state?  I cannot calculate it before it is instantiated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not compute `numCompleted` when you need it that way you don't have to deal with updating it whenever you update the `completed` value of a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a "computed" property, that will change whenever state changes anyway, why not just do this in your component's `render`?

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        name:"Michael",
        tasks:[
            {task:"Go to the gym", completed:false, id:1 },
            {task:"Do yoga", completed:false, id:2 },
            {task:"Buy groceries", completed:true, id:3 },
            {task:"Get tire fixed", completed:true, id:4}
        ]
    }
    render: function () {
      let numCompleted = this.state.tasks.reduce(function (completed, task) {
        return completed + task.completed ? 1 : 0;
      }, 0);

      // render tasks
    }
},
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but how can I pass numCompleted to other components then?

Comment: You'd pass `numCompleted` as a prop just the way you normally would. If multiple sibling / parent components of this component need to know `numCompleted` then that state should be kept somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    var tasks = [
        {task:"Go to the gym", completed:false, id:1 }, 
        {task:"Do yoga", completed:false, id:2 },
        {task:"Buy groceries", completed:true, id:3 },
        {task:"Get tire fixed", completed:true, id:4}
    ];
    return {
        name:"Michael",
        tasks:tasks,
        numCompleted:tasks.filter(function(task) {
            return task.completed;
        }).length
    }
},
```

You can just calculate it if you want...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just calculate that in the following manner:

```
getInitialState: function(){

   var _tasks = [{task:"Go to the gym", completed:false, id:1 }, 
           {task:"Do yoga", completed:false, id:2 },
           {task:"Buy groceries", completed:true, id:3 },
           {task:"Get tire fixed", completed:true, id:4}];

  var completedCount = 0;

  for( var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++ ) {
     if ( task[i].completed ) {
        completedCount++;
     }
  }

   return {
       name:"Michael",
       tasks:_tasks,
       numCompleted: completedCount
   }
```

},